# How to Fix Variable 'fetchRequest' was written to, but never read CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

i have a problem when i call to use NSFetchRequest it complier have display Variable '' was written to, but never read CoreData
How to fix it

[image]

Help me.
P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: It's just a warning saying that you just set the `fetchRequest` and you never use it. Normally, we get data from Coredata like this, `context.fetch(fetchRequest)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined this variable, then set a new value for it, but you aren't using this in the method you've described

To fix this warning, you should use this var or remove it if you don't need it there.